# Delete obsolete wiki'd question?

Tags: discussion

This old question of mine about [OpenOffice file types](https://superuser.com/questions/135517/what-file-types-can-openoffice-read-and-write) is obsolete.

Normally one could just fix it by revising the information but that would just be copying data from the wiki page.

The question came about because I had to download a pdf to get the info and I didn't like that. Now that the information is easily googled the questions reason to exist isn't as strong as it was.

So I'm wondering
should we:

1. copy and paste info from the wikipage to keep it updated?
2. allow a link only answer to the [wiki-page](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Getting_Started/File_formats)?
3. delete the question?

Comment: How is the second option helpful?  Anyone can do a Google search and find the wiki-page, so why make somebody go through another step ( finding this website then clicking a link ), doesn't seem helpful at all.  We should be using the same sources the wiki-page used to come up with our own answer

Comment: @Ramhound - I personally would choose option 3. But going with option 1 we have to keep it updated as the wiki changes or it will be obsolete again next time OO comes with a new version. To "come up with our own answer" as you write, is a bit hard when the answer essentially is a list of file types.  A compromise is option 2, the question can be found here on SU and we don't have to keep it's answer updated. The downside is that we have to break our own rule about "no link only answers".

Comment: I think that was my point;  I would agree the third option is the best in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're not a replacement for another project's wiki page. If all the info is there, there's no need to copy it here, keep it updated, or link to it.

I deleted the question.

Answer (score 3):

I vote for **option 3**, delete the question.

Because going with **option 1** we have to keep the question updated as the wiki changes or it will be obsolete again next time OO comes with a new version.

And to *"come up with our own answer"* as is to avoid a cut´n´paste answer is pretty hard to do as the answer essentially is a list of file types.

The compromise **option 2** has the major downside that we have to break our own rule about "link only answers", the small advantage that question can be found here on SU and we don't have to keep it's answer updated isn't worth it IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, unless it's outdated information and constantly coming up first on Google, I'd suggest against getting rid of it altogether.

A link only answer is never encouraged, as then we just become an Index service, so that option is out.

While a copy-paste is not always the right way, as long as we get the most accurate information, and cite the sources, we should be good, moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

If the wiki in question is not under a [free license](http://freedomdefined.org/Definition), or is restricted from public editing, then it doesn't count: a "community wiki" answer on a StackExchange site, in cc-by-sa, is still more valuable and more deserving of being worked on.